# PowerShell and Google Protocol Buffer technology

Tags: c#, powershell, protobuf-net

I need to use PowerShell for Google Protocol Buffer usage. A language-specific converter has not been found and protobuf-net (C#) was used to generate .cs code and later a .dll file.

All found approaches involved New-Object construction, but public static class Serializer is defined in protobuf-net.dll, therefore an object (class instance) cannot be created ->   New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type ProtoBuf.Serializer.

```
$memory_stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
#######
$obj = new-object ControlInterface.EnableGate
$obj.GateId = 2
$obj.Day = 7
#######
$method = [ProtoBuf.Serializer]
$Serialize = $method.GetMethods() | Where-Object {
                                 $_.Name -eq "Serialize" -and
                                 $_.MetadataToken -eq "110665038"
                                  }
$massive = @($memory_stream,$obj)
$closedMethod = $Serialize.MakeGenericMethod([ControlInterface.EnableGate])
$closedMethod.Invoke($method,$massive)
```

Current error is the following:
Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' cannot be converted to type 'System.IO.Stream'."

Is it possible to avoid C# additional code usage and use only PowerShell means to overcome the issue?

Comment: I'm not a PS person, so I'm unclear: Which is the bit that makes this tricky? The static method? The generic method? Both? Neither? You can avoid the generics via Serializer.NonGeneric.*; any build from r280 onwards also has an instance-based API: TypeModel, typically via RuntimeTypeModel (which is neither generic nor static). Happy to help, but I'm not a PS expert!

Answer (score 1):

It's due to PowerShell casting newly created objects into a dynamic PSObject type, rather than the actual .NET type.

All you have to do is **apply a cast to the object variable declaration**, and your woes go away. (took me ages to find out)

To fix your example:

```
[IO.MemoryStream] $memory_stream = New-Object IO.MemoryStream
#######
[ControlInterface.EnableGate] $obj = new-object ControlInterface.EnableGate
$obj.GateId = 2
$obj.Day = 7
#######
$method = [ProtoBuf.Serializer]
$Serialize = $method.GetMethods() | Where-Object {
                                 $_.Name -eq "Serialize" -and
                                 $_.MetadataToken -eq "110665038"
                                  }
$massive = @($memory_stream,$obj)
$closedMethod = $Serialize.MakeGenericMethod([ControlInterface.EnableGate])
$closedMethod.Invoke($method,$massive)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you are trying to ask but heres some piointers, in PowerShell you call static methods with `::`.

For example:

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("C:\somefile.jpg")
```

But anyway if you want to do it in C# , you can do something like this:

```
$source = @"
public class SampleClass
{
    public static int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }

    public int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
"@

 Add-Type $source
 $obj = New-Object SampleClass
```